# Платы видеозахвата

Tags: драйвер, внешние-устройства

Возможно ли с помощью СВОЕЙ программы получить от драйвера  видеозахвата отдельный кадр с системы видеонаблюдения?

Answer (score 1):

Если ВАША программа уже отображает изображение с камеры, то почему бы и нет? :)

Comment: Вопрос Вами правильно понят?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы у вас, [@Anjei](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5941/anjei), не было сомнений по поводу правильной трактовки **вашего** вопроса, сделайте милость, формулируете его более конкретно. Потому что на данный момент иначе, как «да, можно», на ваш вопрос ответить нельзя.

Comment: Что за, мать ее, эпидемия-то =/ 

@Realetive__, в момент нажатия кнопки "ответить на вопрос" вы понимали, что в поле ввода должен находиться ответ на вопрос? Вы видите ответ в вашем сообщении? Я нет.

Если вы хотели дать "очень общий" ответ, то и в нем желательно дать хотя бы ссылку на пример.

Comment: У пользователей с 2k+ есть опция «сделать комментарием». Хотя я ответ на вопрос в тексте вполне вижу — «да, можно» же.

Comment: Давайте внесем ясность в вопрос, чтобы получить более развернутый ответ:  
1) какая карта видео-захвата используется;
2) имеет ли она драйвер с API-обращением;
3) в какой среде работаете и какой язык вы используете для написания СВОЕЙ программы.

Потому что, если ваша система наблюдения использует ip-камеры, большинство из них позволяют обратиться к ним без сторонних программ по https-протоколу, используя java.

Comment: @drdaeman я в курсе и довольно часто туда тыкаю. Просто последние пару дней я раз 6 такое видел, меня это расстраивает.

@Realetive__, я как бы намекаю, что вы написали комментарий. В комменты принято писать как раз просьбы уточнений, вопросы, претензии и пр. [А в ответ - отвечать на вопрос](http://lurkmore.ru/Капитан_Очевидность). Просто на будущее)

Comment: Не хотелось бы начинать пустую [дискуссию](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80), но я именно так и поступил в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно. Для этого разные библиотеки существуют для разных языков и платформ.